# how to speed up populating a list using TPL(task parallel library) in c#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have following piece of code

```
List<GridVM> _itemsSource = new List<GridVM>();

  foreach(var shelf in Network.Shelves)
   {
        foreach(var equipment in shelf.Equipment)
        {
          var gridVM= new GridVM(equipment);
          itemSource.Add(gridVM);
         }
   }
```

here  _itemSource is a collection that is going to be data source for a grid.

now creating each vm object for each equipment is taking little bit time ~~around 8 seconds. I want to speed up grid data source population using TPL by running inner forloop in different thread and add the vm to the main collection of _itemSource.

How to achieves so using TPL. Will it really speed up my job considering the facts thread overheads and locking overheads. I can convert current list item source to ConcurrentList or ConcurrntBag. but same question :-will it really give any boost or not. if not, then I am interest to know why??

Comment: list is not threadsafe , you gain nothing from tpl here

Comment: @RoyiNamir what if i use ConcurrentList. Will it get me performance boost in any manner considering thread and locking overhead

Comment: You can call the constructors in parallel using PLinq (not sure what you do inside of them to take so much time, but that's besides the point. Something like: `Network.Shelves.SelectMany(s => s.Equipment).AsParallel().Select(e => new GridVM(e))`   Populating a list if almost free, you'll gain nothing from trying to do that in parallel

Comment: @Yogesh Joshi, there's no such thing like `ConcurrentList` instead use `ConcurrentBag` or `ConcurrentQueue`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj sorry for being oversmart but I could use ConcurrenBag

Comment: Use the suggestion by @KooKiz, may add degree of parallelism to it, based on the `Environment Processor Count`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the code you've shown takes 8 seconds? Aren't you assigning later `_itemsSource` to some UI control?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily parallelize your code using PLINQ (aka Parallel Linq):

```
var _itemsSource = Network.Shelves
    .SelectMany(s => s.Equipment)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(e => new GridVM(e))
    .ToList();
```

It may execute faster if the constructor takes time. If the overhead is just "adding items to a list" then you'll gain nothing. That said, if it takes 8 seconds just to add items to the list, then you definitely have other problems, such as memory consumption.